# How do I make my .net winform app stay at 100% text size even if user changes it in the control panel?

Tags: .net, winforms, text-size

I have built a simple app with a single fixed size form window.

When a user goes into Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display in Windows 7 and choose a text size of 125% or 150%, my .net form looks terrible with some controls pushed off the edge.

What is the best way to avoid this issue? Can I fix my app to always be text size 100%?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The best way (and I admit this is not necessarily a helpful answer) is to write your UI so that it resizes gracefully.  People who choose a text size over 100% do so because they can't comfortably read the default size; your job as an application developer is to accommodate their choice.

Comment: +1 Started writing exactly this but got distracted . . . pesky work interfering with SO!